# R create new column of the rank of factors

Tags: r

In R I have a dataframe with two columns one is a value and the other is the group that each value is assigned to:

```
my_group    my_value
A   1.2
B   5.4 
C   9.2
A   1.1
B   5.2 
C   9.8
A   1.3
B   5.1 
C   9.2
A   1.0
B   5.7 
C   9.1
```

I want to create a third column that uses the average of my_value by group to rank the groups and enters that rank in each row:

```
my_group    my_value    my_group_rank
A   1.2 3
B   5.4 2
C   9.2 1
A   1.1 3
B   5.2 2
C   9.8 1
A   1.3 3
B   5.1 2
C   9.2 1
A   1.0 3
B   5.7 2
C   9.1 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will add the group ranks to your data, except that the ranks will be in opposite order, perhaps you can still use it. I use the package `dplyr` for this. In my example, I assume your data is in a data.frame called `test`.

```
require(dplyr)

test <- test %>% 
  group_by(my_group) %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(my_value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(my_group_rank = dense_rank(avg)) %>%
  select(-avg)


#   my_group my_value my_group_rank
#1         A      1.2             1
#2         B      5.4             2
#3         C     10.2             3
#4         A      1.1             1
#5         B      5.2             2
#6         C      9.8             3
#7         A      1.3             1
#8         B      5.1             2
#9         C      9.2             3
#10        A      1.0             1
#11        B      5.7             2
#12        C     10.1             3
```